# Drawing on MIPS. Runtime error

Tags: drawing, mips

have a problem with the following code. I wrote a code for drawig a quater circle on a MARS assembler. But there is an error occurring. The program itself draws the quater circle but in the end there is an error, because of it I cannot use a loop for this procedure, the code is below

```
.data
    DISPLAY: .space 65536    
    DISPLAYWIDTH: .word 128
    DISPLAYHEIGHT: .word 128

.text

j main

set_pixel_color:

    mulu $t0 $a1 $s0 
    add $t0 $t0 $a0
    mul $t0 $t0 4

    la $t2 DISPLAY
    add $t2 $t2 $t0

    sw $a2 ($t2)
    jr $ra          

quater_circle:              
    add $a1 $0 0
    add $a0 $0 0
    lw $a2 RED  

        loop2:
                 jal set_pixel_color
             add $a0 $a0 1
             mulu $t3 $a0 $a0
             mulu $t4 $a1 $a1 
             add $t3 $t3 $t4
             mulu $t4 $a3 $a3

             ble $t3 $t4 loop2                       
             add $a0 $0 $0
             add $a1 $a1 1

             ble $a1 $a3 loop2
             jr $ra 

.data
    RED: .word  0xff0000
    GREEN: .word    0x00ff00
    BLUE: .word     0x0000ff 
.text

main:
    lw $s0, DISPLAYWIDTH    # s0 holds MAX x
    lw $s1, DISPLAYHEIGHT   # s1 holds MAX y
    li $a3 1   
    lw $a2 BLUE
    add $a0 $0 $0
    add $a1 $0 $0
         loop:
             jal set_pixel_color
             add $a0 $a0 1
             ble $a0 127 loop
             add $a0 $0 $0 
             add $a1 $a1 1
             ble $a1 127 loop  
         draw:
              jal quater_circle
              add $a3 $a3 1
              ble $a3 128 draw
```

It ends up with the drawn red quater circle with the blue backround, however it terminates in the end of the procedure, and I cannot use a `draw` procedure. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing `$ra` in your *quater_circle* subroutine.
That routine is called from main and it calls another subroutine (*set_pixel_color*), thus losing original return address.

You should preserve `$ra` in your *quater_circle* subroutine by storing its contents into the stack (and restoring it before returning to the caller) or alternatively moving `$ra` to some other register (e.g, `$s2`) and use it to return.

For the second alternative, you would add

```
  move $s2, $ra
```

at the beginning of *quater_circle* subroutine and change

```
  jr $ra
```

with

```
  jr $s2
```

at the end of the subroutine.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!)